# Getting filtered data with multiple data sets as filters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to build a filter to filter down users with multiple parameters. I realize that the query below is for post meta, but it works the same, and is easier to test on my side.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE (meta_key="_regular_price" AND meta_value="295") 
AND (meta_key="_weight" AND meta_value="2.5")
```

When I do the above code I get no results, but if I change the AND between the 2 sets of brackets to OR it returns both results and from that I can see that there is at least 1 result (post_id) that is in both.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try an OR instead of an AND because its impossible for one `meta_key` to be BOTH `_regular_price` AND `_weight` at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta where (meta_key,meta_value) in (("_regular_price","295"),("_weight","2.5"))
```

Comment: This returns the same result if I change the AND between the 2 sets of brackets to OR. The desired result I'm looking for will only return one or 2 records which matches both of the parameters